# "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" vs. another error

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/stylesheets/style.css">
```

At the end of the page, there are the following scripts:

Case 1: no error, but "hello" was not printed out on console

```
<script>
(function() {
     console.log("hello");
});
</script>
```

Case 2: I got an error: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     console.log("hello");
});
</script>
```

Can you tell me why I got these errors and how I can fix them? Thanks

Comment: Case 1: You don't execute the function. Case 2: Seems like jQuery is not loaded. Any errors in console?

Comment: Yes, and I can't figure out why in the world it's not loaded. "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" is the only error message I got

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use `src` instead of `href` in the `<script>` tags.

Comment: OMG - I just spent 3 hours on this. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Case 1: You're defining the function, but never calling it. You need to put a pair of parentheses after the expression:

```
(function() {
     console.log("hello");
})();
```

Case 2: The correct syntax for `<script>` tags is `src=URL`, not `href=URL`.

Comment: Thanks so much! How do I upvote these answers when I don't have points? lol!!

Comment: @guest - Let me give you some upvotes so you can upvote others :)

Comment: I guess I need to get to 15 before I could upvote these answers

Answer (score 1):

change **href** to **src**

In js we use **src**  and in css we use **href**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

**change to**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks! It's always the little things that trip me over!

Answer (score 0):

1) Maybe you are calling your jquery script before loading the jQuery library.

2) Load your jquery script with `src` instead of `href` in the `<script>` tag.
Maybe you are not loading jquery on your page, try checking if there are any `failed to load resource` errors on your console..hope this helps

3) To know if jquery is working in your website for sure, try this but i hope the above two will solve the issue:

```
(function() {
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        // Standard
        window.addEventListener('load', jQueryCheck, false);
    }
    else if (window.attachEvent) {
        // Microsoft
        window.attachEvent('onload', jQueryCheck);
    }
    function jQueryCheck() {
        if (typeof jQuery === "undefined") {
            // No one's loaded it; either load it or do without
        }
    }
})();
```